# Xcode Archive unusual error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, archive

I am trying to archive my new project, but I have a problem:

[image]

I can run my project on iPhone or iOS Simulator, everything is perfect. But I can't archive it.
So how can I solve it? It's too unusual....

Comment: post error message not images

Comment: rewrite the animateWithDuration method and let the auto-complete work to write full method signature. Might be related the wrong method.

Comment: @Mr.Bista incompatible block pointer type sending 'void (^)(bool)' to parameter of type 'void (^ _Nullable)(BOOL)'

Comment: @Mr.Bista I have rewritten 4 times, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @EdwardChou Clean your build folder and try again. Press alt in keyboard & Select Product from the top menu and then clean build folder.

Comment: @Imad I tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: @EdwardChou which version of Xcode you're using?

Comment: @Imad Version 8.3.2 (8E2002)

Comment: @EdwardChou I tried the same block and created the archive successfully. Mine Xcode version is same as yours.

Comment: @Imad I have solved this problem. I used animateWithDuration: animations: method and performSelector: withObject: afterDelay: method instead of animateWithDuration: animations: completion: method, then I can archive successfully.

Comment: @EdwardChou i understood how u solved ur problem . But, 8.3.2 is supporting ur swift 2.3 code ?